# Select individual edges by source-target-tuple in python igraph

Tags: python, igraph

For a given graph `g` I'd like to change a property, say `'color'`, for a given individual edge, which can be done like this

```
g.es[0]['color'] = some_color
```

However, this requires to know the list index of the edge, here `0`. Assume I only know the source-target-tuple of the edge, say `(0,1)`, is there a simple way to do the above using that tuple, or do I have to iterate throught the whole graph to determine the edge index?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `get_eid` method of the graph object to get the ID of an arbitrary edge between two given vertices; e.g.:

```
g.es[g.get_eid(0, 1)]["color"] = "red"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dict of all source-target tuples pointing at the indexes, this would increase access time greatly.  Of course it only makes sense if you want to do that often; otherwise iterating should be faster.

```
d = { node['source-target']: index for index, node in enumerate(g.es) }
print d[(0,1)]  # will print 0
```

Note: I haven't found the igraph stuff, so I have to guess how to get the source-target tuple out of the nodes; my guess was `node['source-target']` which you probably will have to adjust.

Note also that there might be more than one node which has the same source-target tuple.  In this case you will get only one of them.  If you need all (as a list for instance), we can change that.  Just specify more clearly :)

Comment: Ah I see, your last statement could also be the reason why there is no simple solution like `g.es[(0,1)]`, accessing the node via its tuple is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I've found is to do it this way:

```
g.es.find(_between=((v_src.index,), (v_dest.index,)))
```

Yes, it is weird... the source and target in the `_between` tuple are tuples themselves (and if you use `search` instead of `find`, and multiple start/end vertices are specified, it will return a list of all qualifying edges). If you have an igraph.Vertex, you can get the indices like that; if you already have indices, just use them directly.

There is also a way to do this:

```
# DON'T DO THIS!
g.es.find(_source=v_src.index, _target=v_dest.index)
```

but for some reason, that is a couple of orders of magnitude (!) slower...

```
In [23]: %timeit G.g.es.find(_between=((0,), (4,)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 µs per loop

In [24]: %timeit G.g.es.find(_source=0, _target=4)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop
```